# copy from active to others: selection?

Tags: mesh, materials, selection-tools

I continue to play with the Wrecking Ball tutorial, and am now trying to impose some materials on the huge stack of cubes.  Obviously I should have done this in the beginning, before the first cube was array-duplicated and so on, but here I am with the stack all built, trying to colour them retroactively.  I separated one cube, applied a couple of Materials (darker brown for the sides, lighter brown for top and bottom), and now I would like to xerox those colours onto all the other cubes.

So.  Deselect the template cube, select the whole stack, then re-select the template cube last so that it is Active.  Then use the Special menu in Materials pane to Copy from Active to Others.  But this copies only the primary material, not the contrasting secondary material.  All the cubes are now solid dark brown, whereas I was hoping they would have light brown tops and bottoms.

Is there any way to copy Selection from Active to Others, as in "I have selected the top and bottom faces of this cube, and I want all the other cubes in the stack to have their top and bottom faces selected also, so I can Assign the contrasting colour to them"?  Or is this just a dead-end, and should I delete the lot and start over with a correctly-coloured cube as my master object for creating the stack?  I don't mind the practise in Array modifiers, but I would think that xeroxing a selection pattern from one to many identical objects might actually be useful... so am curious to know if it is do-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the objects you want to copy a set of materials to, and then <kbd>shift</kbd> select object with the finished material.  Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, and choose to link "Object Data".  This will link everything including all the materials and the shape of the object.